# How long does a Python package stay on testpypi?

Tags: python, pypi

How long does a Python package stay on [testpypi](https://test.pypi.org/)? It seems very difficult to find this information so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyPI administrator here: currently there is no limit to how long releases might remain on TestPyPI, but you should not to *expect* them to remain indefinitely.

Comment: Okay good, I only want a few weeks while I work out some bugs.